# Kotlin: get members of a data class by reflection in the order they have been defined

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Assume the following simple example data class:

```
data class SomeDataClass(
  var id: String,
  var name: String,
  var deleted: String
)
```

With the following code it is possible to get the properties (and set or get their values):

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

val properties = SomeDataClass::class.memberProperties

print(properties.map { it.name })   // prints:   [deleted, id, name]
```

The map within the print statement will return a *List* with the name of the properties in alphabetical order. I need the list in the order they have been defined in the source code, in this case: [id, name, deleted].

It doesn't seem achievable purely through reflection. The only solution I could come up with is to use a helper class defining the order:

```
val SomeDataClass_Order = listOf("id", "name", "deleted")
```

This wouldn't be a problem for one or two classes, but it is for hundreds of data classes with the largest one having up to almost one hundred properties.

Any idea would be welcome. I do not need detailed code, rather hints (like parsing the source code, annotations, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the properties are declared in the primary constructor, you could "cheat":

```
val propertyNames = SomeDataClass::class.primaryConstructor!!.parameters.map { it.name }
```

If you want the `KProperty`s:

```
val properties = propertyNames.map { name -> 
    SomeDataClass::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == name } 
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't find the properties that are declared in the class body.

I don't know about other platforms, but on Kotlin/JVM, the order in which the backing fields for the properties are generated in the class file is not specified, and a quick experiment finds that the order (at least for the version of kotlinc that I'm using right now), the order is the same as the declaration order. So *in theory*, you could read the class file of the data class, and find the fields. See this [related answer for getting the methods in order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38929813/5133585). Alternatively, you can use Java reflection, which also doesn't guarantee any order to the returned fields, but "just so happens" to return them in declaration order:

```
// not guaranteed, might break in the future
val fields = SomeDataClass::class.java.declaredFields.toList()
```

If you do want to get the properties declared inside the class body in order too, I would suggest that you don't depend on the order at all.

Comment: You saved me with ...::class.java.declaredFields.toList().

Comment: @lukas.j I should warn you again that the order is not guaranteed, and can very well break in other Kotlin compiler versions and/or JDK versions.

Comment: I'm aware of this. I need this only for a one-time transfer from a legacy system to a new application. I use to create exports to Excel files, so a team of employees can check data quickly and correct it in the legacy system before it is imported into the new one. And for these non-IT-employees the order of the columns in the Excel files is important.

Comment: You saved me too. I can confirm this works still today, December 2023, on whatever the current kotlinc version is.