# How to generate JSON in declaration order of fields using struts2-json plugin

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

```
class Bean
{
    private String x,y,z,a,b,c;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Using struts2 json plugin, the json that gets generated for the above bean is in [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

This [reference], says that since [JDK 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001172/java-reflection-getting-fields-and-methods-in-declaration-order) it is supported in declaration order, but in JSON response, I see the fields arranged in lexicographic order.

Is there any way to achieve declaration order in the generated JSON ?

Comment: I did this... but I forget how at the moment (not at home computer) but I do remember that I asked a question to do with this (on here). If I recall it was using the java compiler API or a related API and reflection, using that you can figure out the line number of the declarations (or anything else really), and use that for conventions. Which makes a lot more sense than using annotations. You'll need a custom JSON result too!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148274/java-get-declared-methods-in-order-they-apear-in-source-code & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834887/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-a-method/14973713#comment21272750_14973713 - They suggest to write my own json plugin.

Comment: One of them also suggests that it works for declaration order in JDK 6, but I'm using 7 and it's not like that.

Comment: Right Javassist should do mostly what you need, but the declarations need to be on separate lines (if going by declaration, otherwise your code could determine order by getter/setter if that proves to be ambiguous. (as it would be in your case))